# Duda rápida punteros y deducción de tipos decltype(expr)

Tags: c++11

tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
template <typename T>
auto array_access(T& array, size_t pos) -> decltype(array[pos])
{
       return array[pos];
}

std::vector<int> vect = {42, 43, 44};
int* p = &vect[0];

array_access(vect, 2) = 45;
array_access(p, 2) = 46;
```

Tengo un par de preguntas sobre este fragmento de código, la primera creo que es rápida y la segunda quizás un poquito mas complicada.

1ª Duda:(Es de conocimientos básico)

No entiendo en la segunda llamada a `array_access(p,2)`, porque se le pasa `p`, cuando p es la **dirección** de `vect[0]`.Yo le habría pasado `*p`, es decir el valor, ya que la función `array_acceso`, espera una `&`. No se si estoy  haciendo algo mal, o es que las plantillas al recibir un puntero deducen de alguna forma que no se.

2ª Duda:(relacionada con decltype en ambas llamadas).

- En la primera llamada `decltype(vec[2])`, el operador `[]` de `std::vector<int>` devuelve una `&`, luego nos devuelve en nuestro caso al ser vector de enteros, `int&`, a su vez esto es lvalue luego `decltype(lvalue)` nos devuelve `T&`, aplicando collapsing rules `int& &` es `int&`.
- **La segunda llamada tengo dudas de como se comporta**. En este caso le estamos `p[2]` es `int`, es un lvalue, luego `decltype(prvalue)` nos devuelve `T&`, quedando entonces, el tipo deducido `int&` ¿es correcto?.

Answer (score 0):

### 1ª Duda

> ya que la función array_acceso, espera una &

Esa afirmación es falsa. La función no espera una `&` sino que es la propia función la que recoge una referencia de la variable que se le pase:

- Si le pasas una variable por valor la función recoge una referencia a dicho valor.
- Si recibe un puntero, la función recoge una referencia a dicho puntero

El ejemplo funciona porque una característica de `std::vector` es que los elementos se encuentran en posiciones consecutivas de memoria. Si utilizases otro contenedor (por ejemplo `std::list`) esta característica no estaría garantizada y no podrías acceder a los elementos con un puntero tan alegremente... sería bastante peligroso.

Así pues, mientras no añadas elementos al vector ni llames a determinadas funciones como `std::reserve`, que pueden mover los datos de sitio, el vector es equivalente a un array de tamaño fijo.

Las siguientes variables serían, en este aspecto, equivalentes:

```
std::vector<int> vect = {42, 43, 44};
std::array<int> array = {42, 43, 44};
int array2[]          = {42, 43, 44};
```

### 2ª duda

> En la primera llamada decltype(vec[2]), el operador [] de std::vector devuelve una &, luego nos devuelve en nuestro caso al ser vector de enteros, int&, a su vez esto es lvalue luego decltype(lvalue) nos devuelve T&, aplicando collapsing rules int& & es int&

No es del todo correcto... `decltype()` sirve para **evaluar** la instrucción que se le indica. Así, en el siguiente ejemplo, `var2` será de tipo `int`:

```
var = 10;
decltype(var) var2;
```

Pues bien, en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
std::vector<int> vect = {42, 43, 44};
decltype(vect[1]) var = vect[1];
```

`var` va a ser de tipo `int&`, ya que `vect[1]` devuelve una referencia de tipo `int`:

```
T& std::vector<T>::operator[](size_t index);
```

De hecho puedes verificar facilmente lo que te digo quitando la asignación al declarar la variable:

```
std::vector<int> vect = {42, 43, 44};
decltype(vect[1]) var /* = vect[1] */;
```

El programa no compilará porque las referencias tienen que ser inicializadas obligatoriamente.

Así que, resumiendo, lo que está sucediendo en este caso es que el tipo retornado por `array[pos]` es una referencia de tipo `int`, luego el tipo de retorno de la función será igualmente una referencia de tipo `int`... aquí no influyen ni los *R-value* ni los *L-value*.

> La segunda llamada tengo dudas de como se comporta. En este caso le estamos p[2] es int, es un lvalue, luego decltype(prvalue) nos devuelve T&, quedando entonces, el tipo deducido "int&" ¿es correcto?.

En este caso `T` se sustituye por `int*`, luego `array` será una referencia a un puntero de tipo `int` (realmente que en este caso sea referencia o no es irrelevante). El caso es que la especialización que conseguimos es:

```
auto array_access(int* & array, size_t pos) -> decltype(array[pos])
{
   return array[pos];
}
```

Y hemos dicho que la referencia en este caso es irrelevante, así que supongamos que la especialización (para simplificar) es la siguiente:

```
auto array_access(int* array, size_t pos) -> decltype(array[pos])
{
   return array[pos];
}
```

En este caso, `array[pos]` es **una referencia** al elemento ubicado en la posición `pos`. De hecho no es un misterio que tu puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int array[10];
array[3] = 1;
```

Y no olvidemos que si podemos modificar el elemento `3` es porque `array[3]` nos está devolviendo una referencia a la posición 3... luego `decltype(array[3])` se convertirá en `int&`

Comment: Sobre esto:Si recibe un puntero, la función recoge una referencia a dicho puntero.Si le paso p, en array se guarda, *p?.

Comment: @Jcpardo no... si pasas `p` la función recibe `&p`. Si `p` es de tipo `int*` la función recibe `int* &array`, es decir, una referencia a un puntero

Comment: Y porq dices esto, me pierdo en este punto. Disculpa la torpeza.Y hemos dicho que la referencia en este caso es irrelevante, así que supongamos que la especialización (para simplificar) es la siguiente:

Comment: Pensando puede ser que se elimine la referencia por la deducción de tipos en plantillas? Que es igual que trabaja auto salvo pequeñas diferencias?

Comment: @Jcpardo las diferencias entre `auto` y `decltype` debería ser una pregunta aparte

Comment: @Jcpardo no termino de entender tus preguntas así que difícilmente voy a poder responderte

Comment: No entiendo porque dices que la **referencia es irrelevante**, en este punto.El caso es que la especialización que conseguimos es:

auto array_access(int* & array, size_t pos) -> decltype(array[pos])
{
   return array[pos];
}
Y hemos dicho que la **referencia en este caso es irrelevante**, así que supongamos que la especialización ...

Comment: @Jcpardo la referencia es irrelevante porque no aporta nada en ese caso. La idea es simplificar el caso para que sea mas entendible. Si no vas a modificar la dirección del puntero no vas a ganar nada con la referencia al puntero